# changing timezone affects cron time

Tags: linux, timezone, time

I have set up a cron to run at every 26th minute.

```
$ crontab -l
26 * * * * date > /home/time.txt 2> /home/time_err.txt
```

The current time shown by date command.

```
$ date
Thu Aug 25 23:26:00 CDT 2011
```

The cron runs as expected but when I add the hour field to the cron, it does not work.

```
42 23 * * * date > /home/time.txt 2> /home/time_err.txt
```

Recently the system Admin changed the timezone of this server to CDT from EST.
Is the cron problem because of that?
How do I correct this?

Comment: What does 'not work' mean? The datetime in `time.txt` is wrong?

Comment: Cron does not run. No change to time.txt file.

Comment: Did you take a look at `/var/log/cron` to make sure that cron is not running?

Comment: Thanks. looking at the cron it was clear that the cron DID run. User cron could not overwrite a file created by root cron.

Comment: @shantanuo: Please post your answer to this question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the log it was clear that the cron DID run. User cron could not overwrite a file created by root cron